# FQL query for comments_fbid suddenly returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-comments

I've been using the following code for quite a while now to retrieve my comment + comment reply count total via Facebook FQL. However, today it just stopped working and is now returning an empty array. I think I've traced to to the fact that FB is not returning a `comments_fbid` for the given URL.

```
select time, is_private from comment where is_private = 0 and object_id in 
(select comments_fbid from link_stat where url ='MY_URL') or 
is_private = 0 and object_id in (select post_fbid from comment where object_id 
in (select comments_fbid from link_stat where url ='MY_URL'))
```

This request usually would return an object with a `length` equal to that of the total comment count.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This issue is caused by a bug in FQL.

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/317008698404331

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a bug. comments_fbid returns NULL even though there are comments on this particular URL.

Track it here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/317008698404331